# Check if object has specific keys from another array

Tags: php

I need to modify each user object in array by adding missing keys and values of "-"

Currently I have while loop that gets lists each new value into array called "Headers" and also grabbing each object and placing them into "Users" array.

```
$headers = array("Firstname", "Lastname", "Email", "Age");
$users = array(
array(
"id" => 32,
"user" => "{ 
   Firstname: 'John', 
   Lastname: 'Smith',
   Email: 'example@pleasehelp.com' 
 }
),
array(
"id" => 32,
"user" => "{
 Firstname: 'Josh', 
 Lastname: 'Pellow', 
 Age: '22' 
}
)
);
```

I want this:

```
$users = array(
array(
"id" => 32,
"user" => "{ 
   Firstname: 'John', 
   Lastname: 'Smith',
   Email: 'example@pleasehelp.com',
   Age: '-'
 }
),
array(
"id" => 32,
"user" => "{
 Firstname: 'Josh', 
 Lastname: 'Pellow',
 Email: '-', 
 Age: '22' 
}
)
);
```

Each user object should contain each value from Headers array with or without value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$headers = array("Firstname", "Lastname", "Email", "Age");
$users = array(
    array(
        "id" => 32,
        "user" => array(
   'Firstname'=> 'John',
   'Lastname'=> 'Smith',
   'Email'=> 'example@pleasehelp.com'
 )
),
array(
"id" => 32,
    "user" => array(
        'Firstname'=> 'Josh',
        'Lastname'=> 'Pellow',
        'Age'=> '22'
    )
));
echo '<pre>';


$i=0;
$newArray=array();
foreach($users as $row){
    (isset($row['user']['Firstname']) ? $newArray[$i]['Firstname']= $row['user']['Firstname'] : $newArray[$i]['Firstname']='-');
    (isset($row['user']['Lastname']) ? $newArray[$i]['Lastname']= $row['user']['Lastname'] : $newArray[$i]['Lastname']='-');
    (isset($row['user']['Email']) ? $newArray[$i]['Email']= $row['user']['Email'] : $newArray[$i]['Email']='-');
    (isset($row['user']['Age']) ? $newArray[$i]['Age']= $row['user']['Age'] : $newArray[$i]['Age']='-');
    $i++;

}

print_r($newArray);
```

And the output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Firstname] => John
            [Lastname] => Smith
            [Email] => example@pleasehelp.com
            [Age] => -
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Firstname] => Josh
            [Lastname] => Pellow
            [Email] => -
            [Age] => 22
        )

)
```

Comment: No sorry this wasn't it, because answer is not dynamic and you are dealing with arrays as where I am with objects.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All I had to do is loop each user and check for header value in **array_key_exists**!

```
        foreach($users as $user){
            //get user from user row
            $row = $user['user'];
            //loop headers for each row
            foreach($headers as $header){

                //check if $header found in each row
                if (!array_key_exists($header,$row)){
                    //if not found
                    $row->$header = "-";
                }

            }
        }
```

[w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_array_key_exists.asp)